# how to insert unicode values in mysql 5.1 version using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, c#-4.0, phpmyadmin

In my asp.net application, i have some data in unicode format(Hindi-Indian language).Now i want to insert this unicode text into mysql(5.1) database.When i run the below C# code, the text stored in my db as like **??????** instead of my unicode text.But when i execute the query through **phpmyadmin** it was stored correctly.

I already set the db,table and particular field collation as **utf8_general_ci**. and also set the db character set to **utf8**.

```
string mysql_query2 = "SET NAMES 'utf8'";
da.UpdateCommand = new MySqlCommand(mysql_query2, mysqlCon);
da.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();


string para_text="हिन्दी भारत";
string para_outerxml="की राष्ट्रभाषा";
string status="जयपुर। हास्य-व्यंग्य";

string sql = "Insert into sand_box (para_text,para_outerxml,status) values('" + para_text + "','" + para_outerxml + "','" + status+")";
da.InsertCommand = new MySqlCommand(sql, mysqlCon);
da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Also, Please refer my image below.(Table Structure)

[image]

Comment: I don't know whether it would help in this case, but you should move to using parameterized queries instead of including your values directly in the SQL... not least to avoid SQL injection attacks. It's just *possible* that that will also help in terms of Unicode, although I doubt it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need it to cast into `base-64` and insert it as follow

```
var langText = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("yourtext"));
```

And while fetching back convert it to normal string as follows

```
var Normal=Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String("your base64text"));
```

### Edit 1

So your insert should be like

```
string mysql_query2 = "SET NAMES 'utf8'";
da.UpdateCommand = new MySqlCommand(mysql_query2, mysqlCon);
da.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();


string para_text="हिन्दी भारत";
string para_outerxml="की राष्ट्रभाषा";
string status="जयपुर। हास्य-व्यंग्य";

string sql = "Insert into sand_box (para_text,para_outerxml,status) 
     values('" + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(para_text)) + "','" 
             + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(para_outerxml)) + "','" + 
              Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(status))+")";
da.InsertCommand = new MySqlCommand(sql, mysqlCon);
da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

### Edit 2

Here is a similar question
[how to insert arabic into mysql from asp.net C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441787/how-to-insert-arabic-into-mysql-from-asp-net-c-sharp/13441874#13441874)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 5.1 supports two character sets for storing Unicode data:

```
ucs2, the UCS-2 encoding of the Unicode character set using 16 bits per character.

utf8, a UTF-8 encoding of the Unicode character set using one to three bytes per character.
```